# Basic Jmeter Framework for Functional testing

Tags: frameworks, jmeter, reusability

Does anyone know or have implemented a basic framework in Jmeter which helps achieve re-usability and robustness.

I currently have 4 API's (upload file, get details, update file, delete file)

Now i need to test this for different formats.

I initially took the approach of putting all 4 api's in a thread group and disabling that group.

Then i called each api's using a  **module controller** for different formats of the file.
[image]

This helped me achieve reusability but then asserting responses and extracting response using regex. extractor, became difficult and next to impossible.

Is there a way to achieve ***reusability*** in Jmeter? Module Controller works but it doesn't allow regex extractor which can inturn be used for assertion.

Instead of adding multiple assertions and regex extractors in every HTTP call, i would like to add it once and then probably reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues while implementing complex functional tests for a large web application. I used components mentioned below to achieve reusability:

```
Module Controller 
Parameterized Controller
Loop Controller
IF controller
Beanshell & JMeter functions
```

You should not face any issue with use of Regex extractor under any controller. For conditioning you can use **IF controller** and Beanshell.
**Parameterized controller** is extremely useful if you need to use same samplers but with different datasets/values.

[image: Snapshot of JMeter Test Plan]